# Pulling CSV files into Oracle and MySQL database

Tags: informatica

I am creating several Informatica jobs to pull CSV data files from different third party servers and would wish to ingest and load this data into different databases, both oracle and SQL. I have sample data files and I am looking for anyone to assist me create the jobs or provide me with a template to assist me. The biggest problem is that some CSV files holds data for more than two or three tables and it is becoming very hard for me to know how to transform the files. Again, I am looking at a way on how to automate the loading of the daily CSV files

Comment: Hi, if you want to write (parts of) a source filter to multiple targets then just use a Router transformation

Comment: Hi! We'll be happy to support your efforts, answer questions and help solving issues. Please describe what you have done so far and what are you struggling with. Note, that this is not forum to look for freelancers and it may be not possible to find someone that would assist by doing some pair programming.